# Group rows when one column's number value is between or following two other columns values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the flowing problem. I have a data frame as follow:

| Country_code | country | low_range | high_range |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AU | Australia | 1 | 10 |
| FR | France | 2 | 40 |
| FR | France | 4 | 60 |
| AU | Australia | 11 | 23 |
| AU | Australia | 21 | 23 |
| AU | Australia | 30 | 43 |
| AU | Australia | 43 | 55 |
| FR | France | 46 | 55 |
| FR | France | 67 | 80 |
| FR | France | 81 | 98 |

I would like to get an output such as:

| Country_code | country | low_range | high_range |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AU | Australia | 1 | 23 |
| FR | France | 2 | 60 |
| AU | Australia | 30 | 55 |
| FR | France | 67 | 98 |

so that for France for example, all this rows are merged as one:

| Country_code | country | low_range | high_range |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FR | France | 2 | 40 |
| FR | France | 4 | 60 |
| FR | France | 46 | 55 |

output:

| Country_code | country | low_range | high_range |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FR | France | 2 | 60 |

And

| Country_code | country | low_range | high_range |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FR | France | 67 | 80 |
| FR | France | 81 | 98 |

output:

| Country_code | country | low_range | high_range |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FR | France | 67 | 98 |

How can I merge rows with a similar country or country_code so that I can get a row with a range from the lowest range number to the highest range number ? But only if all the merged rows have number in the final row range number ?

Note that my data frame is already order by low_number values.

My level in Pandas is low. However I already group by countries:

```
countriesGroup = df.groupby(['country'], as_index=False)
```

I then unsuccessfully tried to groupby on one specific country using a condition:

```
france = countriesGroup.get_group('France')
france.groupby(france['high_range'] == france['low_range'].shift(1) + 1).agg( { 'high_range': max, 'low_range': min})
```

I don't know how to keep all the other columns while replacing the low_range value by the min value  and the high_range by the high value using agg or any other function.

I also already asked a similar question but it was just to merge row with the same low_range as the next line high_range. The answer was :

```
df.rename(columns={"high_range":"key"}).merge(df.rename(columns{"low_range":"key"})).drop(columns="key")
```

This is perfect for my previous use case but I do not see how I could adapt it to the new one.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You had the right idea using `groupby`, but you can use aggregator functions such as `min()` and `max()` instead of ordering your values and shifting your data.

My solution uses `groupby` as you suggested, but then I extract the minimum value for `low_range` and the max value for `high_range`, and finally I loop through the original values in your data to create a new `df` that appends to a new output dataframe `df_out`. The new row is build as a dict and appended using `pd.concat`.

```py
# Groupby countries
df_groupby_countries = df.groupby("country")

# Create empty output dataframe
df_out = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)

# Create list of country names/codes in your data to loop through
lst_country_names = df_groupby_countries.groups.keys()
lst_country_codes = list(df["Country_code"].unique())

for country, code in zip(lst_country_names, lst_country_codes):
    # Extract min/max values from groupby for current country
    high_range = df_groupby_countries["high_range"].max()[country]
    low_range = df_groupby_countries["low_range"].min()[country]
    
    # Append new row to new dataframe
    df_out = pd.concat(
        [df_out, pd.DataFrame([{"Country_code": code, 
                                "country": country, 
                                "high_range": high_range, 
                                "low_range": low_range}])],
        ignore_index=True
    )

print(df_out)
```

Output:

|  | Country_code | country_name | low_range | high_range |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AU | Australia | 1 | 55 |
| 1 | FR | France | 2 | 98 |

Comment: Thank you for your response Adam Jaamour, sadly what I'm looking for is :
Australia|1|23, France|2|60, Australia|30|55, France|67|98
Where rows are merged only when the numbers follow each other and are included in the final range. For example, for France, we have a hole between 60 and 67 so those two rows cannot be merged.